# SQL alias not identify

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

Please help me to correct the query. Here the alias "startDate" not identify.

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.[ID]                         
    ,b.[Name]
    ,a.[VName]
    ,a.[StartKM]
    ,a.[RecurringKM]
    ,dateadd (day,-(120000 - a.[StartKM])/80,GETDATE())as startDate
    ,dateadd(day,(a.[RecurringKM]/80),[startDate])as [DueDate]
FROM MaintenanceEventInstance AS a
INNER JOIN MaintenanceEventDescriptor AS b ON a.ID=b.ID
WHERE a.VName='test' AND a.CompletedDate  IS NULL AND 
    a.ReType='4' 
order by [DueDate] asc
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can not use an alias in a secon Parameter in select

Comment: oh ! okay thanks. I will try another way.

Comment: use a CTE or derived query. Else is to use the full expression in the DueDate computation.

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the alias in the `SELECT` clause. Try this instead:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.[ID]
            ,b.[Name]
            ,a.[VName]
            ,a.[StartKM]
            ,a.[RecurringKM]
            ,x.startDate
            ,dateadd(day,(a.[RecurringKM]/80),x.[startDate])as [DueDate]
FROM MaintenanceEventInstance AS a
INNER JOIN MaintenanceEventDescriptor AS b ON a.ID=b.ID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT dateadd (day,-(120000 - a.[StartKM])/80,GETDATE())) AS x(startDate)
WHERE a.VName='test' AND a.CompletedDate  IS NULL AND 
      a.ReType='4' order by [DueDate] asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use column alias in same select, instead add the expression there,

```
SELECT TOP 1 a.[ID]
            ,b.[Name]
            ,a.[VName]
            ,a.[StartKM]
            ,a.[RecurringKM]
            ,dateadd (day,-(120000 - a.[StartKM])/80,GETDATE())as startDate
            ,dateadd(day,(a.[RecurringKM]/80),dateadd (day,-(120000 - a.[StartKM])/80,GETDATE()))as [DueDate]
FROM MaintenanceEventInstance AS a
INNER JOIN MaintenanceEventDescriptor AS b ON a.ID=b.ID
WHERE a.VName='test' AND a.CompletedDate  IS NULL AND 
    a.ReType='4' order by [DueDate] as
```